# Codekit + Less / CSS minification

Tags: css, less, minify, codekit

So I would like to get Codekit to minify all my css + less files Upon save.

In the header of my 'style.less' I am trying to import the 'css' file as a less context like:

```
@import (less) "normalize.css"; 
@import (less) "file1.css"; 
@import (less) "file2.css"; 
@import (less) "file3.css"; 

body {....
```

In the hope it will sort of be 'included' then minified on save. I cant seem to get it to work with any combination of @import, saving the css files as less files.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

So my issue was trying to @import font replacement. When looking inside the font replacement file there was an import happening over another site. I believe this is what was causing the miniification to fail...

Hope this helps someone else.